# how do I make an int variable defined as either this OR that?

Tags: xcode4

To be more specific here is my code

```
-(IBAction)randomnumber {

    int rNumber1 = rand() % 10; 
    textview1.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber1];

    int rNumber2 = rand() % 10;
    textview2.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber2];

    int rNumber3 = rand() % 10; 
    textview3.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber3];

    int rNumber4 = rand() % 10; 
    textview4.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber4];
}
```

and this is the just of what i want to do with the first int...

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"A" @"B"...

int rNumText1 = rand() % 10 or keys; 
textview1.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", rNumText1];
```

So basically I want a text "Label" to output either a random A-Z or a random 1-9 after the user hits a button on the ipod.

For example I could have 16 of these things and each would randomly chose between outputting a number or outputting a letter, then pick that random letter or number to output like this:

number, letter, letter, number, etc
and the next time 
letter, letter, number, letter, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like so:

```
int rNumText1;
int random = rand() % 36;
if(random < 10)
    rNumText1 = random
else
    rNumText1 = keys[random-10];
```

Or more compactly:

```
int random = rand() % 36;
int rNumText1 = (random < 10) ? random : key[random-10];
```

Comment: Wayne thank you so much I've been scratching my head for a while now and couldn't find an answer elsewhere      p.s how do i make more than one of these outputs, just put a 2 after the first & second random on the bottom example?

Comment: You could use an array of integers, and then loop through the array, using the bottom example as the body of the loop (modified to work with an array, of course!)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, but why not just put the strings "1" to "9" in the array as well and then pick a random number between 0 and 31 (inclusive) and use that as the index to the array?